# how to use roboto font in css using xhtml

Tags: css, html, primefaces, fonts, xhtml

I've using xhtml,jsf and primefaces. I've mentioned my styles in css file. I want to add roboto font in my project. So i tried for adding font and got some solution, like adding below line in XHTML

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

But i don't want to add this line `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css`to my code.
I want to add it through .CSS and XHTML file except web link.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You have to include `<link>` elements anyway if you want to use CSS, so what's one more? Or don't you want any `<link>` elements at all, just a `<style>` block? Then just put an `@import` in the `<style>`. If you were hoping you could do this through inline style attributes, you're out of luck.

Comment: Ah, it's the Google APIs you want to avoid; that wasn't very clear in this question; I only understood that after reading your other one.

Answer (score 0):

Google Fonts offers three distinct ways to embed fonts, all of which are clearly described on their Quick Use page:

#### Standard

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

#### @import

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Roboto::latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); </script>
```

These are the only ways to include them — or any web font for that matter.

You could go the route of using a Data URI for the font files

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,<YOUR_BASE_64_ENCODED_FILES_SOURCE>) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```

but that's highly discouraged as it would add unnecessary bloat to your page. Also, I'm not sure what the expected benefits of this approach would be in your case. It's usually only useful for very small binary files (~1-2k).